# Fit Border around arbitrary Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Path based on a group of rectangle/ellipse Geometry. When I put an auto-sized Border around it, the border shrinks to fit the RectangleGeometry but does something weird with the EllipseGeometry, as shown below. Anyone know how to fix it so the Border (shown in blue) fits snugly around the whole thing?

Ultimately, I want a Border or a Panel that fits an arbitrary, runtime-generated Path (including the stroke thickness), and I need the geometry size maintained.

[image: screenshot]

Sample code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Path Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="-10,-10" RadiusX="12" RadiusY="12" />
                <EllipseGeometry Center="70,0" RadiusX="70" RadiusY="10">
                    <EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-25" CenterX="50" CenterY="0" />
                    </EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                </EllipseGeometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set the Path's `Stretch` property and bind its `Width` to the Width of the Bounds of the Geometry:

```
<Path ... Stretch="Uniform"
          Width="{Binding Data.Bounds.Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    ...
</Path>
```

As the Geometries's Bounds do not contain the rendered Path's `StrokeThickness`, you may alternatively put the Border into a Canvas (which does not resize its child elements at all), and don't set the Path's Width. This may may however lead to problems when you want to center the Canvas in an outer Grid. It's actual size appears to be zero.

```
<Canvas>
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
        <Path ... Stretch="Uniform">
            ...
        </Path>
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: To keep the scale while generating at runtime you could further extend this with `Width="{Binding Bounds.Width, ElementName=geoGroup}"`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have mentioned that I need the geometry to remain the size it was defined. Funk, is there a way to make that work that includes the stroke thickness? It's still scaling down to fit the stroke in.

Comment: @JVimes You may use a Binding Converter that adds a fixed value to the Width, or use a MultiBinding where you also pass the StrokeThickness, or use a method like [GetWidenedPathGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615692(v=vs.110).aspx) to calculate the exact bounds.

Comment: Or don't set the Width at all, and put the Border in a Canvas.

Comment: Ah, thanks Clemens! The Canvas and Stretch approach is perfect for me. An extra panel doesn't hurt my situation.